# Subsetting Variables

Tags: r, subset, analysis, measurement

I'm currently working with a fairly large data set and am looking to subset some of my variables.

I'm essentially trying to select a range of variables then add one single variable in that function, and switch back to selecting a range.

For example:

```
items_data = subset(dataset, select = q1:19, q20, q33:35, q50)
```

However I think the commas are causing some issues.

I've been scouring the interwebs for a solution, but have only come across scripts that are more cumbersome, and I know there's an easier solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess c(q1:q19, q50) would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

**Base R**

```
items_data = dataset[,c(1:20, 33:35, 50)]
```

**Dplyr**

```
#install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)

items_data = select(dataset, 1:20, 33:35, 50)
```

note that the numbers are column index positions, if your dataset changes, so will the columns it will pull. You can also use the names of the columns instead, to ensure that if your dataset changes, it will retain pulling the same fields.

Comment: The dplyr, this would work with column names as well: `items_data = select(dataset, q1:q20, q33:q35, q50)` (assuming the columns are in order -- it uses table order, not numeric values)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Matt W. and MrFlick! Worked very well.

Comment: No problem @Darko